# fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted

Tags: php, sockets, web-hosting, fopen, fwrite

so the project I'm working on was working fine on localhost with xampp but when I uploaded it on Godaddy I got this error

`PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted in /home/randomnumbers/public_html/domain.com/lib/QueryAPI.php on line 61`

Line 61:
`fwrite($this->rSocket, $sPacket);`

it works fine on localhost so it has something to do with Godaddy, is there anything I should enable through cPanel to get it to work? I use the economy Linux plan, I enabled sockets in cPanel, but still doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: It sounds like the port you are trying to use is blocked by Godaddy. Are you trying to use a custom port? try the default port

Comment: Try `phpinfo()` on your server and see if there is any socket functions which are disabled. If so, you may ask your hosting provider.